# Asignar valor PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un problema al momento de asignar una tarea al usuario. Es que se repite

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debe de asignar el id del users.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Excepto el status **0**

el codigo que estoy implementando:

```
$iCnt = 1; /// cuando no hay valor en la base de datos asignar automaticamente el valor 1
$cout = $db->query("SELECT id_users,COUNT(id_users) FROM trabajo GROUP BY id_users HAVING COUNT(id_users) > 0 ORDER BY COUNT(id_users) DESC LIMIT 1");
if ($row_cnt = $cout->fetch_array()) {
    $idusers = $row_cnt['id_users'];
        /// aca he pasado un buen rato pensando como hacer para que me asigne antes de escribir el post.
            if ($idusers = 1) {
                $iCnt = 2;
            } elseif ($idusers = 2) {
                $iCnt = 3;
            } elseif ($idusers = 3) {
                $iCnt = 4;
            } elseif ($idusers = 4) {
                $iCnt = 5;
            } elseif ($idusers = 5) {
                $iCnt = 6;
            } elseif ($idusers = 6) {
                $iCnt = 7;
            } elseif ($idusers = 7) {
                $iCnt = 8;
            } elseif ($idusers = 8) {
                $iCnt = 9;
            } elseif ($idusers = 9) {
                $iCnt = 10;
            } elseif ($idusers = 10) {
                $iCnt = 11;
            } elseif ($idusers = 11) {
                $iCnt = 12;
            } elseif ($idusers = 12) {
                $iCnt = 13;
            } elseif ($idusers = 13) {
                $iCnt = 14;
            } 
            
}
```

Lo que se quiere es que asigne al usuario el trabajo automaticamente evaluando la cantidad de trabajo que tiene y asi no sobre cargar de trabajo.

Antes que todo muchas gracias

---

Añado informacion:

Cuento las veces que el `id_users` se repite en la tabla trabajo, el que tiene mas trabajo.

En la primera imagen se puede apreciar que el `id_users` *(9)* se repite 5 veces, como el registro llega hasta el 9 debe de empezar nuevamente en 1 y el `id_users` *(1)* debe de tener 5 para empezar el ciclo de nuevo.

---

Actualizacion de codigo:

```
    $sql7 = $db->query("SELECT id_propuestas,id_users,COUNT(id_users) FROM trabajo GROUP BY id_users HAVING COUNT(id_users) > 0 ORDER BY COUNT(id_users) DESC LIMIT 1");  

/// realiza el conteo los trabajo que tiene y indica cual es el id que tiene mas trabajo asignado.

    if ($row7 = $sql7->fetch_array()) {
        $idusers = $row7['id_users'];
        
        
    }
    
    $pro = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"); 

// Para saber cual donde termina el id_users y no hace el largo if & elseif
    if ($rwx = $pro->fetch_array()) {
         $rx = $rwx['id']; 
    }
    if ($rx != $idusers) {
        $query7 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `status` = 1 AND id > '".$idusers."' ORDER BY id ASC limit 1");  

// me indica cual es el proximo numero que le sigue.
 
        if ($cnt7 = $query7->fetch_array()) { 
    
        }
    } elseif ($idusers == $rx) {
        $id2 = 1;
    } else {
     echo $id2;
    }
```

Comment: no logro entender bien lo que intentas hacer, podrías detallar mas? y cual es tu lógica para evaluar la sobre carga de trabajo

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo ya modifico y agrego mas informacion

Comment: @TomassTeran, todos esos if() elseif()...te los puedes ahorrar poniendo simplemente: "$iCnt = $idusers+1;". Si tienes que añadir alguna otra condición, en un único if() puedes hacerlo.

Comment: Hola @cooper Gracias por la sugerencia, es valida pero como vez en la posicion 3 y 4 no debe de ser tomada y en caso que mas adelante alguna de esas cuenta sea desactivada y agreguen nuevas cuenta.

Comment: @TomassTeran, sólo una cosa más. En los if() debes establecer una doble igualdad: if($idusers == ...)

Comment: @cooper he establecido `==` / `!=` / `<=` / `>=` y aun sigue con el mismo inconveniente que repite